# Reason for parameter for using custom fields in configuration

Tags: development, com-fields

In the Joomla Core Extensions we have a parameter for selecting if custom fields are used in an extension or not. For example here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/administrator/components/com_contact/config.xml#L369

I wonder if I need this in my custom extension, too?

What is the reason for this parameter? You can just leave the custom fields unused.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessary need it.
I think it may be a bit of a performance factor and also UI cluttering if you have custom fields enabled but not used. For core, it was decided to make it opt-in.

In my own extension, I have no parameter for it.